# Splitting up Data into Rows based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

First time here so apologies in advance if I'm asking this incorrectly.

I have a pretty good understanding of excel but I've only ever really used it for some easy to moderate formulas. I'm trying to figure out where to start with a problem I have but I'm not even sure what to search for to find the answer. From what I have been able to find - it should be achievable with either Power Query or a Excel-VBA macro?

I have maybe 400 rows of data on a sheet. I need to separate each row of data based on the values in 4 of the columns.

This is the screenshot I've made with a brief example of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

The top part of the screenshot is how the data is now. The bottom part is how I want the data to be modified. A new row is created for any fee thats been incurred (base fee for every row, then if they have incurred an order fee then a new row is added, if a priority fee has been incurred then a new row is added etc. If it's '0' then no new row).

If any one has any guidance on how to do this it'd be great. I'm not asking for the solution, but just some tips on what I can research or what I should be learning to accomplish something like this!

Comment: Excel VBA, it's like Visual Basic. If don't know some basics of programming it will be hard for you.

Comment: Excel macros are written in VBA (I think). Looks like a pivot table to me. Maybe that is something to search for. Although I might try to do it in VB.net I don't think that is best. I would add the VBA tag and remove VB.net.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Apologies not sure why I put VB.net! I meant VBA. I've worked with VB.net / C# a lot but never involving Excel. I'll keep doing research! :)

Comment: If this is your first time with VBA, maybe it will be easier to do it with formulas.
Check this out, maybe it will help http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VectorToMatrix.aspx
The oposite is described in a link at the end of that page, that with some filters should do it

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry, so this code is rushed. Can come back and explain things if needed. But it gives me the output you've shown.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UnpivotColumns()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lastSourceRow As Long
    lastSourceRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastSourceColumn As Long
    lastSourceColumn = sourceSheet.Cells(1, sourceSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Dim sourceData As Range
    Set sourceData = sourceSheet.Range("A2", sourceSheet.Cells(lastSourceRow, lastSourceColumn))

    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    destinationSheet.Cells.Clear
    destinationSheet.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Name", "Description", "Currency", "Fee")

    Dim destinationRowIndex As Long
    destinationRowIndex = 1 ' Skip header row

    Dim outputArray(1 To 4) As Variant ' Re-use same array throughout procedure

    Dim sourceRowIndex As Long
    For sourceRowIndex = 2 To lastSourceRow

        ' Base fee always needs writing (unconditionally)
        outputArray(1) = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, "A") ' Name
        outputArray(2) = "Base Fee"  ' Description
        outputArray(3) = "USD" ' Currency
        outputArray(4) = 150 ' Fee amount

        destinationRowIndex = destinationRowIndex + 1
        destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value = outputArray

        Const FIRST_COLUMN_TO_UNPIVOT As Long = 4 ' Skip first three columns

        Dim sourceColumnIndex As Long
        For sourceColumnIndex = FIRST_COLUMN_TO_UNPIVOT To lastSourceColumn Step 2
            outputArray(2) = sourceSheet.Cells(1, sourceColumnIndex)  ' Unpivoted description
            outputArray(3) = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, sourceColumnIndex + 1) ' Unpivoted currency
            outputArray(4) = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceRowIndex, sourceColumnIndex) ' Unpivoted fee amount

            ' Skip amount if nil/zero
            If outputArray(4) > 0 Then
                destinationRowIndex = destinationRowIndex + 1
                destinationSheet.Cells(destinationRowIndex, "A").Resize(1, 4).Value = outputArray
            End If

        Next sourceColumnIndex

    Next sourceRowIndex

End Sub
```

The code makes some assumptions (which are true for your screenshot, but might not be true if the layout of your data changes).

Bad things about this code:

- It is rigid and not very flexible/dynamic
- It will be slow as it read/writes cells one at a time.
- There is no referential integrity (column indexes/offsets are assumed and never actually checked/asserted). This becomes a problem if the layout/position of your data changes.

Good things about this code:

- It hopefully works (for the example you've shown in your screenshot).

This is my data before the code (on `Sheet1`):

[image: Before]

This is my data after the code (on `Sheet2`):

[image: After]

Also, something like this is equally possible in Power Query too (and probably in fewer lines of code too).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column headers in your example (Name, Email, Order Date, Order Amount, Currency, Expedite Fee, Currency, Courier Fee, Currency) with the source data in named range with headers Table1, the powerquery code would be below.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Base Fee", each "USD:150"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom", {{"Order Amount", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Currency", "Order Amount"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Order Amount1"),
#"Merged Columns1" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"Expedite Fee", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Currency2", "Expedite Fee"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Expedite Fee1"),
#"Merged Columns2" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns1", {{"Courier Fee", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Currency3", "Courier Fee"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Courier Fee1"),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Columns2",{"Name", "Order Amount1", "Expedite Fee1", "Courier Fee1","Base Fee"}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Other Columns", {"Name"}, "Description", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Currency", "Fee"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Split Column by Delimiter","1","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Description"})
in #"Replaced Value"
```